# Folder Permissions IIS 7 server. Denying acces to folder to web browsers

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, permissions, directory

I'm new to servers and i would like to ask a simple question.

I've got a website (aspx) with a folder where i store images.

Mobiles connect through http client (generic handlers) and can download images from the folder, but i want to deny the access to this folder to web browsers so the images can't be seen.

How could i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you really want to restrict it, keep that image or file folder inside App_Data. Then no one can accidently change the permission, and only handler can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use something like this

```
<configuration>
<location path="MySubDirectory">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/> <!-- Denies all users -->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Mmmm that worked but only for that folder, how can i extend that to all subfolders?

Comment: hmm, I don't think you can use a wildcard for the path. I'd probably just drop another web.config in that folder and use the same as above minute the location part

Comment: The problem is that that folder may have thousands of folders that are constantly changing... ^^

Comment: May be most painless to move these to a folder that isn't under a web application. So if you're app is running on c:\inetput\coolApp maybe move the folders to C:\appData\CoolApp\AwesomeFiles

Comment: True... i'll try that but i'll have to learn how to specify absolute paths to HD. Never tried.

Comment: Cool, I think you should be able to get it without issue. If you have some problems post up a comment!